# Setting and getting session-bound attribute in spring

Tags: java, spring, thread-safety, multi-tenant

I have followed a tutorial on [dynamic datasource routing](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) tutorial in Spring. For that I have to extend AbstractRoutingDataSource to tell spring which datasource to get, so I do:

```
public class CustomRouter extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return CustomerContextHolder.getCustomerType();
    }
}
```

Everything goes fine till I find the class responsible for keeping the value of the customerType (it should be the same during the whole session):

```
    public class CustomerContextHolder {

        private static final ThreadLocal<Integer> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<Integer>(); 

        public static void setCustomerType(Integer customerType) {
            contextHolder.set(customerType);
        } 
        public static Integer getCustomerType() {
            return (Integer) contextHolder.get();
        }
        public static void clearCustomerType() {
            contextHolder.remove();
        }
    }
```

This creates a thread-bound variable customerType, but I have a web application with spring and JSF I don't think with threads but with sessions. So I set it in the login page with thread **A** (View), but then thread **B** (Hibernate) request the value to know what datasource to use, it is `null` indeed, because it has a new value for this thread.

Is there any way to do it Session-bounded instead of Thread-bounded?

Things I have tried so far:

- Inject the CustomRouter in the view to set it in the session: Not working, it causes a cycle in dependecies
- Replace the `ThreadLocal` with an Integer: Not working, the value is always set by the last user logged in

Comment: why is hibernate executing in another thread?

Comment: Shouldn't it be? When I debug the DAO methods, I see there is a different thread accesing the method each time. Is this wrong?

Comment: As far as I know the servlet containers use a thread per request, that means when an HTTP request is made, a thread is created or retrieved from a pool to serve it and only one thread. So a different thread accesing the method is OK only if that thread is serving a different request.

Comment: That's why it has different values, because for a new thread a new ThreadLocal would be created I guess. So I need to store it in the session somehow, that is persistent between requests

Comment: ThreadLocals are not created when a new Thread is running. Instead It stores a new value weak referencing the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` working? If so then you may try with this:

```
public class CustomerContextHolder { 

    private static HttpSession getCurrentSession(){
             HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                 .getExternalContext().getRequest();

             return request.getSession();
    }

    public static void setCustomerType(Integer customerType) {

       CustomerContextHolder.getCurrentSession().setAttribute("userType", customerType);

    }

    public static Integer getCustomerType() {

        return (Integer) CustomerContextHolder.getCurrentSession().getAttribute("userType");
    }

    public static void clearCustomerType() {
        contextHolder.remove(); // You may want to remove the attribute in session, dunno
    }
}
```